# Execute a function after component is fully ready

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have an angularjs component, which has a template, a controller, some bindings, some transcluded parts.

I place this component in my DOM, together with its attributes:

```
<mycomponent attr1="x" attr2="y"></mycomponent>
```

These attributes values will be used by component's controller and/or in the component's template to be transcluded somewhere.

I need to run a function **after** the component has been completely created, i.e. it's template has been created on the DOM **and** all the transcluded elements have been given a value.

How can I accomplish that? I tried placing the function in the $postLink() hook of the controller, however when $postLink() fires I see that the transclusion has not run yet.

Moreover, I don't like to have to mess with component's controller, since the component is very general, I place it on several places in the DOM, and only ONE of them should run this function after its complete creation.

Answer (score 1):

For AngularJS 1 application, there are two ways of running a function after DOM initialization :

1. You can use $timeout without a delay - $timeout(function() { /* Invoke your function */ });
2. Or Use .ready() which is provided by Angular's jqLite

Comment: I found this to be the case for AngularJS 1. There is no lifecycle method or hook to use. $onInit does not guarantee that the component's view and child views are finished loading on the UI, and $viewContentLoaded is not used on a component.

Answer (score 1):

From ["Components have a well-defined lifecycle"](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/guide/component) paragraph in AngularJS docs:

> **$postLink()** - Called after this controller's element and its children
>   have been linked. Similar to the post-link function this hook can be
>   used to set up DOM event handlers and do direct DOM manipulation. Note
>   that child elements that contain **templateUrl** directives will not have
>   been compiled and linked since they are waiting for their template to
>   load asynchronously and their own compilation and linking has been
>   suspended until that occurs. This hook can be considered analogous to
>   the **ngAfterViewInit** and **ngAfterContentInit** hooks in Angular 2. Since
>   the compilation process is rather different in Angular 1 there is no
>   direct mapping and care should be taken when upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

**In Angular 2:**

**ngAfterViewInit()**

Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views.
Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked().
A component-only hook.

**in Jquery:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "document loaded" );
    });
```

**in javascript:**

```
window.onload(function(){
//here
});
```

**in angular1:**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        //content here
    });
```

Comment: Question ask for AngularJS, the v1, and as far as i know from v1.5 there is the $onInit lifecycle hook method.